# Stability of Solutions to Ordinary Linear Second Order Differential equations with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am wondering about what happens to the solution of a linear ODE $ax'' + bx' + cx = 0$ as $b^2-4ac$ gets close to 0 from above. It seems to me like going from $b^2-4ac=0.01$ to $b^2=4ac$ shouldn't dramatically change the solution, so $\displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} c_1e^{(3+ \epsilon)t} + c_2e^{(3 - \epsilon)t} = (c_3 + c_4t)e^{3t}$ for suitable $c_3, c_4$ just to give an example, but this doesn't look true to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix the initial conditions to better compare the behaviour of the solutions. Then
$$
c_1+c_2=y(0)\text{ and } c_1(3+ϵ)+c_2(3-ϵ)=y'(0)
$$
resulting in 
$$
ϵ(c_1-c_2)=y'(0)-3y(0)
$$
already indicating that the values of $c_i$ will grow as $O(1/ϵ)$. Solving for $c_i$ and combining similar terms one gets
$$
y(t)=e^{3t}·\cosh(ϵt)·y(0) + e^{3t}·\frac{\sinh(ϵt)}{ϵ}·(y'(0)-3y(0))
$$
and for $ϵ\to0$ you get $\frac{\sinh(ϵt)}{ϵ}=t+O(ϵ^2t^3)$.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly are you doing after "Composing that one gets"?

Comment: Solving the linear system. With $c_1+ c_2=a$ and $c_1-c_2=b$ you get $c_1=(a+b)/2$, $c_2=(a-b)/2$. So that $c_1e^u+c_2e^{-u}=a\cosh(u)+b\sinh(u)$.